# Remove visual appearance of "Adjust image when focused" in tvOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have an `UICollectionviewCell` with a fullsize image (Constrains: 0,0,0,0).

I added an optional image (a 'watched image') above the full screen image. This works.

Due to the fact that there is a 'Zoom effect' if the cell is focused, I have to enable the `Adjust image when focused` attribute. Now both images resizes as wished.

The problem is, that this feature adds a grey shadow layer to the 'watched' label which is not good.

Thats why I need the feature of the resizing but without the visual appearance of it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, try to move the 'watched image' in the same level as your collection view but comes after the collection view in the view hierarchy. This should place your optional view on top of your collection view cell and avoid the shadow from falling on top of it.